# Send SMS in iOS 7 it not work

Tags: sms, send

```
- (IBAction)button_number1:(id)sender {


MFMessageComposeViewController *textComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

[textComposer setMessageComposeDelegate:self];

if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

    [textComposer setRecipients:@[string_numberphone]];

    [textComposer setBody:@"ABC"];

    [self presentViewController:textComposer animated:YES completion:NULL];

} else {

    NSLog(@"Can't Open Text");

}
```

}

}

when I click a button_number1, it does not work, and no arlet Error.

But when clicking the button below, it works normally on iOS 7 but I can not assign the message content.
Please guide me how to assign the message content to this button_number2.

```
- (IBAction)button_number2:(id)sender {
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"sms:%@",string_numberphone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:message ]];
```

}

Thank so much!

Answer (score 0):

in .h header file.....

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>{
- (IBAction)sendsms:(id)sender;

}
```

in .m implementation file.....

```
- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender{
if (phoneNumber!=NULL) {



            UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
            if ([[device model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] ) {

                NSString *phNo = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
                NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@",phNo]];

                if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
                } else
                {
                   UIAlertView *calert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Call facility is not available!!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [calert show];
                    [calert release];
                }

            } else {

                UIAlertView *warning =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Your device doesn't support this feature." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                [warning show];
                [warning release];
            }
        }
        else {

            UIAlertView *warning =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Phone No is not Available." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [warning show];
            [warning release];
        }

}
```